# Using PyTesseract to extract text from multiple files at once

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am building a Python service that receives a batch of images, runs them individually through PyTesseract via the `pytesseract.image_to_string` method, and returns the text extracted from each one inside a list. It's working just fine, but we were looking to improve its performance. Our first attempt involved using `pool.map` from Python's multiprocessing library to break the list of images into smaller parts and process those using different cores. But the processing time actually went up.

So we started looking towards sending all images simultaneously to PyTesseract, hoping the fact it would be loaded just once would improve the service. PyTesseract allows that with the command `pytesseract.image_to_string('images.txt')`, with the text file that is passed holding the address where each image is saved.

Doing so visibly made the processing faster. Sadly, PyTesseract actually concatenates the text extracted from all images in the file into one large string, making it virtually impossible to know which part of the text came from which image.

So my question is: is there a reliable way to do what we are trying to do, whether it is using PyTesseract itself or another library?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could use a lighter model which should be faster: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_fast